# Tensorflow object detection api. Detecting 90 default classes + n new classes at a time

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, computer-vision, conv-neural-network, object-detection-api

I am using tensorflow object detection api. I was able to detect default 90 classes using pre-trained models. 
I was also able to detect only custom objects (Ex: `macncheese`) by training on new dataset that has only `macncheese`. 
I am having a hard time trying to combine 90 (default)+ 1(`macncheese`) object classes for detection. I heard of the solutions like training the 91 classes
from scratch by adding a new dataset to the coco original dataset. I am also trying to go back 1 layer of the pre trained model and train only the new data
to detect 91 classes. I am new to computer vision so i am not well versed with training a CNN. can you please suggest some solutions.

Model used: Single shot detector.
OS: Windows 10
Platform: Anaconda

Answer (score 0):

If you want all 91 classes to be recognized, you would have to retrain on training date set which has all 91 classes. Like you did for the one macncheese. Is there any specific question beyond this you are struggling with?

Comment: Currently I only have training data for macncheese. So I labeled it manually, created xml and converted it into csv's and TF records. Pretrained model is built upon MSCOCO dataset. Can I get labeled data for MSCOCO. I know there is annotations file in http://cocodataset.org/#download . But it is not in the same format as xml and I am not able to comprehend the json file in annotations. Can you let me how I can club xml information of macncheese with annotation file of MSCOCO and create a TF record. MSCOCO dataset has 25GB images. Is there a way out without downloading all those images?